# Using appropriate word in a sentence!

Tags: grammar

A non native English speaker says
"I was *hunting* a jacket for my son at mall"
For, me "hunting" is not an appropriate word here. How can I explain this concept?

Comment: Could you explain why you think it is not appropriate?

Comment: In this context, it means searching, looking, tracking down from a large choice. So a bit like hunting.

Comment: Well, I think that simply "looking for a jacket" can work here.

Comment: @Madeeha - You are right, "looking for a jacket" *can* work here.  The speaker uses *hunting* to show that the jacket being sought was as difficult to find as a certain difficult-to-hunt animal in the forest might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a *direct object* with the verb "to hunt," it means you are stalking and killing game:

> The shooting party **hunted** *deer* and *elk*.

If you want to express the fact that you're looking assiduously for something, make that something the *object of the preposition* "for":

I **was hunting** for *a jacket* for my son at mall